# has_secure_password is saving password in plain text

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm using Robert Reiz's guide [here](http://robert-reiz.com/2014/04/12/has_secure_password-with-rails-4-1/) about using `has_secure_password` in Rails 4 to generate secure password hash's for a User model. I've generated the model and controllers, and the page works, I can submit the form in `new.html.erb` and it saves the data to the database and everything, **but the password isn't hashed, it's just saved in plain text**.

Here is my User model (user.rb):

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

has_secure_password
    EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}\z/i
    validates :username, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :length => { :in => 3..20 }
    validates :email, :presence => true, :uniqueness => true, :format => EMAIL_REGEX
    validates :password, :length => { :minimum => 5 } 
    validates_confirmation_of :password
end
```

If there are any other files you need to see, I'm happy to add them :)

EDIT: Here is the migration file:

```
class CreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

def change
    create_table :users do |t|
      t.string :username
      t.string :password_digest
      t.string :email

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Do you have the `bcrypt` gem installed? Also, you shouldn't have to specify that you want to validate the confirmation of :password, the `has_secure_password` has that built in as long as the confirmation field is called `password_confirmation`.

Comment: Can you reproduce this within a new app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've provided no information about your model, yet

> It requires a field ‘password_digest’ in your model, where it will
>   store the encrypted password:
>
> ```
> rails g model user username:string password_digest:string
> ```

After you create your model, which creates the migration file, then you have to create the table in the db by executing the migration, which isn't mentioned in the tutorial:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

Did you do that?

Also, the tests in that tutorial are blatantly wrong.  They should look like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe User do

  it "fails because no password" do
    User.new({:username => "hans"}).save.should be_false
  end

  it "fails because password to short" do
    User.new(
      username: "hans", 
      password: 'h',
      password_confirmation: 'h').save.should be_false
  end

  it "succeeds because password is long enough" do
    User.new(
      username: "hans",
      password: 'hans is great',
      password_confirmation: 'hans is great'
    ).save.should be_true
  end

end
```

Finally, running the tests won't create any users in the *development db*--it will create users in the *test db*, and after the tests are done running, the users in the test db will be destroyed, so when the tutorial says to look in the db--you can't.

What you can do is use the *rails console* to make sure things are working correctly:

```
$ rails console
```

Then create a User:

```
2.0.0-p481 :001 > my_user = User.new(username: 'Hans', password: 'hello', password_confirmation: 'hello')
 => #<User id: nil, username: "Hans", password_digest: "$2a$10$9MHFgIAdODbYBZEBSJGpL.HBbrWOnp0nV7BDm/8oN.yB...", created_at: nil, updated_at: nil>
```

See the encrypted password_digest?  Then you can do:

```
2.0.0-p481 :002 > my_user.save
...
...
```

Then if you check your *development db*, you should see that User's info in the db, along with the encrypted password_digest field.

> Do I need to change the :password fields in the model to
>   :password_digest?

Did you already have a User model before starting the tutorial?  If so, you either needed to rollback your create_users migration:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:rollback
```

..then destroy the User model:

```
$ rails destroy model User
```

...then create a new User model with the appropriate columns.

Or, create a migration that added a `password_digest` column to your existing User model:

```
$ rails generate migration add_password_digest_to_users password_digest:string
```

Then execute the migration:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
```

...and prepare the test db:

```
$ bundle exec rake test:prepare
```

For an alternate tutorial on `has_secure_password`, see the [railstutorial](http://rails-4-0.railstutorial.org/book/modeling_users).

Comment: I've already created the `password_digest` field (I've basically followed his guide and added Email and Username fields). Do I need to change the `:password` fields in the model to `:password_digest`?

Comment: @TomOakley,  No.  But, you need to provide all the information, so post the migration for you model.

Comment: Sorry, I'm relatively new to Ruby/Rails. By migration, do you mean the file in `db/migrate`? If so, I've added it to the OP.

Comment: @TomOakley, Your migration file looks fine, so no problems there.

Comment: @7stud this worked, thanks! A little fiddly but it's all good, thanks the help :)